# How to Point a Dreamhost Domain Name to a GoDaddy Server

Tags: server, ftp, dns, godaddy, dreamhost

I have a domain name example.com with Dreamhost. I also own a dedicated server with GoDaddy.

(1) How do I configure the domain name system, so that the Dreamhost domain name is hosted at the GoDaddy dedicated server?
(2) How do I set up the file transfer protocol for the website?

Answer (score 1):

For the naked domain (eg, `stackoverflow.com`), add an `A` record for the hostname `@` pointing to the IP address for the GoDaddy server.

For other subdomains, add a `CNAME` record pointing to the domain name of the GoDaddy server.  (For compatibility reasons, a naked domain cannot have a `CNAME`)

To find the IP address or domain name, or to use FTP, consult the GoDaddy documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your domains settings in dreamhost. Then click on DNS link under the domain name. You'll find CNAME records setting over there. Just enter the nameservers of godaddy in this field. Save the settings and in few hours it'll point to godaddy servers.

Once you point nameserver to respective host, the FTP and control panel settings apply only if you "add domain" via Cpanel or their control panel. If the domain name is not added in your hosting account, it's not going to let you install scripts and use FTP option. So check godaddy docs for how to add domains once you point the domain name to godaddy serer.